# How to create a master process in Python under Linux?

Tags: python, linux

When running, [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) (a python daemon) then a `ps aux | grep gunicorn`, you get a process for each worker and a master process.

If you kill the master process, you kill them all.

How to do this in Python?

Is there a way for each process to communicate with each other (sending data, reponding to it asynchronously, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `multiprocessing` module to create the worker processes. In order to get the behavior you want, you need to implement a signal handler that will catch common kill signals, terminate the worker processes, and exit gracefully.

Since gunicorn is open-source, you might also want to take a look at the code.

Comment: +1. Waiting for somebody that would come with a code example. If None, will accept this one.

Comment: I'd like to +1 once more for making me discovering bitcoins. But I can't :-)